# how to generate different floats between [0,1]

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'd like to use NumPy randomly generate different numbers between closed interval [0,1].
np.random.uniform(0,1) gives me the totally same numbers, but that is not what I want. I expect 0.606, 0.278, 0.981, 0.699 these kinds of random numbers in the Frequency column.
np.random.randn(0,1) gives me an error.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

````
```
df = pd.DataFrame ({
'isRetention': ['T']* 28017 + ['F']* 31037,
'Frequency': np.random.uniform(0, 1)
 })
df



isRetention Frequency
0   T   0.60612
1   T   0.60612
2   T   0.60612
3   T   0.60612
4   T   0.60612
... ... ...
59049   F   0.60612
59050   F   0.60612
59051   F   0.60612
59052   F   0.60612
59053   F   0.60612
```
````

Comment: `np.random.uniform` is only being called once.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thank you for the reply! How to call it many times to generate many different numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't your `isRetention` be True/False instead of the character T/F?

Anyhow, you were broadcasting a single random value over the whole dataframe. Try this instead:

```
isRetention = ['T']* 28017 + ['F']* 31037
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'isRetention': isRetention,
    'Frequency': np.random.uniform(0,1, len(isRetention))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you call `np.random.uniform(0, 1)` only one time, so the d['Frecuency'] will be filled with that only value. You can try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame ({
'isRetention': ['T']* 28017 + ['F']* 31037,
'Frequency': np.random.uniform(0, 1,28017+31037)
 })


print(df)
```

Output:

```
      isRetention  Frequency
0               T   0.665864
1               T   0.646582
2               T   0.984343
3               T   0.662025
4               T   0.866976
          ...        ...
59049           F   0.261724
59050           F   0.882630
59051           F   0.422858
59052           F   0.515343
59053           F   0.366749
```